# cv2.namedWindow freezes in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi-desktop

I'm trying to open a namedWindow using openCV in raspberry pi but it freezes after `cv2.namedWindow("image")`line. However, the project works in Windows. Before it freezes it prints the following warnings:

```
(python3:959): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:34:34.421: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'

(python3:959): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:34:34.421: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(python3:959): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:34:34.421: g_object_new_with_properties: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

Comment: Are you sure that `cv2.namedWindow("image")` is enough to reproduce the problem? On an unrelated note, raspberry-pi-desktop doesn't run on RPi 4, it's a PC/Mac OS. You probably mean `raspbian`.

Answer (score 0):

[PROBLEM SOLVED]

I am developing GUI with PyQt5.

I got error messages after running this code:

> (python3:2306): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:38:58.937: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'
> (python3:2306): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:38:58.938: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
> (python3:2306): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:38:58.939: g_object_new_with_properties: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

```
def SelectROI(self):

    #cv2.imshow("Select Region of Interest", self.browsed_img4)
    ImageToCrop = self.tmp_4.copy()
    

    r = cv2.selectROI(ImageToCrop)
     # Crop image

    imCrop = ImageToCrop[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]
```

The problem occurs when u are using different gtk version... For my case I was using gtk2 in QT configuration but in my machine I am using gtk3.

[Solution]

edit qt5ct.conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf
# replace style=gtk2 with style=gtk3
ctrl+x y ENTER
```